# `size_t` in NSString stringWithFormat

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, stringwithformat

i have a `size_t`variable i would display in a `NSLog`. This variable contains the number of bytes sent.

if i use this: `NSLog(@"%zu",myvariable);` i have no error message but the number overflows and the NSLog output keeps showing numbers below 32.768. why is that? isnt Long supposed to show values ranging in value from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 through 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 ?

here is some code. i want to show in NSlog self.bufferOffset, that should be the approx ammount of bytes sent.

```
        // If we don't have any data buffered, go read the next chunk of data.

        if (self.bufferOffset == self.bufferLimit) {
            NSInteger   bytesRead;

            bytesRead = [self.fileStream read:self.buffer maxLength:kSendBufferSize];

            if (bytesRead == -1) {
                [self stopSendWithStatus:@"File read error"];
            } else if (bytesRead == 0) {
                [self stopSendWithStatus:nil];
            } else {
                self.bufferOffset = 0;
                self.bufferLimit  = bytesRead;
            }
        }

        // If we're not out of data completely, send the next chunk.

        if (self.bufferOffset != self.bufferLimit) {
            NSInteger   bytesWritten;
            bytesWritten = [self.networkStream write:&self.buffer[self.bufferOffset] maxLength:self.bufferLimit - self.bufferOffset];
            assert(bytesWritten != 0);
            if (bytesWritten == -1) {
                [self stopSendWithStatus:@"Network write error"];
            } else {
                self.bufferOffset += bytesWritten;
            }

        }

             NSLog (@"%lu",self.bufferOffset);
```

and here is some of the output:

```
  2013-02-24 15:54:39.674 prog[298:303] 32768
  2013-02-24 15:54:39.728 prog[298:303] 4820
  2013-02-24 15:54:39.791 prog[298:303] 10820
  2013-02-24 15:54:39.853 prog[298:303] 16580
  2013-02-24 15:54:39.911 prog[298:303] 23780
  2013-02-24 15:54:39.965 prog[298:303] 28100
  2013-02-24 15:54:40.024 prog[298:303] 32768
  2013-02-24 15:54:40.080 prog[298:303] 6852
  2013-02-24 15:54:40.139 prog[298:303] 14052
  2013-02-24 15:54:40.197 prog[298:303] 18372
```

Comment: Are you compiling in 64-bit mode?

Comment: i am pretty new to xcode so i am not sure where to look for that. if it is the information shown at the top left saying "My Mac 64-bit" then yes.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is not with `myvariable` but from the source of the assignment to `myvariable`. What platform is this on, iOS, OSX?

Comment: show some code, %zu is ok

Comment: code added.. check first post

Comment: Perhaps `kSendBufferSize` is 32768? If I understand your code correctly, `self.bufferOffset` will always be less than or equal to `kSendBufferSize`. - And `%zu` works perfectly with `size_t` on 32-bit and 64-bit platforms.

Comment: @martin R this is not my code, its the code from the simpleFtpsample from apple. i think you're correct... i thought that it worked in a different way. checking and will  report back soon..

Comment: Also NSLog `bytesWritten as well as `self.bufferOffset` both prior to the assignment and after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.bufferOffset` in your code is the offset of the first read-but-not-yet-written byte in the buffer, therefore you will always have

```
 self.bufferOffset <= kSendBufferSize
```

This (hopefully) explains why the NSLog() output is limited by 32768.

`self.bufferOffset` is not the total number of bytes written.

*Remark:* As others already have commented, the `%zu` format works correctly with a `size_t` variable. On a 64-bit platform, `size_t` is a 64-bit unsigned integer. Example:

```
size_t s = 18446744073709551615ULL; // 2^64-1
NSLog(@"%zu", s);
// Output: 18446744073709551615
```

Comment: thanks, youre right! i will ahve to add anotehr variable and start counting there by adding the written values on reach run.

Comment: do you have an idea by the way how i can retrive the total size of the file beeing sent? thanks!

Comment: @Justme: `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:&error]` returns a dictionary with file attributes. The file size is one of the attributes.

Comment: thanks! any idea why this: `self.totalbytes = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:&error] valueForKey:NSFileSize ];` returns something like 691079367 instead of 2699528? thats 350 times the actual filesize. `filePath` is correct.

Comment: @Justme: No, but I would 1) check the dictionary return value first, 2) check the error, 3) use `objectForKey` not `valueForKey`.

Comment: thanks,! 1) done, value inside the dictionary is correct 2) no errors 3)done but the value inside self.totalbytes is still wrong. self.totalbytes is defined as long.

Comment: @Justme: `objectForKey` returns a `NSNumber` object. You have to apply  `longLongValue` to convert that to a scalar type.